# Usage of "presumed" with present/past tense in a subordinate clause

Tags: verb-forms, subordinate-clauses, tense-agreement

"Everyone presumed that I am weak person"

Is this wrong?

vs.

"Everyone presumed that I was weak person"

Is this always right?

Comment: If you are still a person who is weak, then statement 1 is correct. If you were a weak person, then statement 2 is correct. By the way, what do you feel about the two sentences? Why do you feel that sentence 2 is always correct?

Comment: You need to add some context as to what is happening around your statement, time-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is incorrect because both verbs should be in the past tense.

The the second statement is almost correct. It should be:

"Everyone presumed that I was A weak person."

If you were the only weak person in a group of people you'd use THE instead of A.

If I said this in American English, I'd leave out "person" because it's assumed that I'm a person. I'd just say:

"Everyone presumed that I was weak."